# To apply a:active css to the active link through JSF

Tags: css, jsf

I am trying to change the active menu border bottom color i.e the bottom colour should change when the menu is active.

This is my JSF code:

```
<h:head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="#{request.contextPath}/resources/css/cir.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form prependId="false">
        <div id="styleHead">
            <h:commandLink value="Home" action="disclaimer.xhtml" />
            <h:commandLink value="About" action="aboutCir.xhtml" />
            <h:commandLink value="Legal" action="legal.xhtml" />
        </div>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Below is my CSS:

```
#styleHead a {
    border-bottom-color:#497693;
}
#styleHead a:hover {
    border-bottom-color:#F7A824 ;
}
#styleHead a:active {
    border-bottom-color:red ;
}
```

CSS `a:active` disappears after the page is redirected to some other page. I have tried using JavaScript to apply the CSS but that makes it disappear after the page reloads.

I tried using `<f:param>` with commandlink but that too was in vain.

Is there any way to apply active css to the active link through jsf or through managed beans?

Comment: Do you understand that JSF is only a framework for generation of HTML/JS/CSS code within the context of your question? You need to explain what goes wrong better: what do you mean by 'disappears', etc. Another point is, do you understand what `:active` pseudo-class means?

Comment: Yes i Understand what is JSF. When i click on a particular link, the a:active style get applied but when i redirect the link to some other page the a:active style applied goes away. This is my problem.